# How to create a handle for a structure/array inside a FORTRAN routine?

Tags: pointers, fortran, handler

I need to create an handle for an fairly complicated structure (here replaced with "real a(2)") in a subroutine and then only pass back the handle/pointer to the main routine. I also need to be able to create as many as of these structure that are needed.
The problem is that the data structure will be deallocated once the pointer is returned to main. Here is my attempt:

```
  program main
  implicit none

  integer i, j
  real a(2) ! This can be a complicated structure

  a=(/1.1,2.2/)
  call myalloc(a,i)

  a=(/3.1,4.2/)
  call myalloc(a,j)

  call myprint(i)      
  call myprint(j)

  stop
  end
```

c-----------------------------------

```
  subroutine myalloc(a,i)
  implicit none

  real, pointer :: i(:) ! If I add "save" attribute I will get an error
  real, target :: a(2)

  allocate(i(2))
  i => a

  return
  end
```

c--------------------------------

```
  subroutine myprint (i)
  implicit none

  real, pointer :: i(:)

  print *, i

  return
  end
```

c---------------------------------

The result is some garbage values:
3.93764868E-43  1.40129846E-45

Or I would get:
At line 41 of file test.f (unit = 6, file = 'stdout')
Internal Error: list_formatted_write(): Bad type

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong with this code it is almost too difficult to answer constructively.

If I understand what you are trying to do, the subroutine `myalloc` is supposed to act like a copy constructor of sorts - allocate memory onto a supplied pointer and then copy the contents of an initializing argument onto the memory allocated. So the key error in your myalloc is these two lines:

```
  allocate(i(2))
  i => a
```

Here you first allocate memory to the pointer `i`, then assign `i` to point to `a`. Why allocate i at all in this case? I presume this is closer to what you are trying to do:

```
subroutine myalloc(a,b,n)
  implicit none

  real, dimension(n) :: a
  real, pointer,dimension(:) :: b
  integer :: n

  allocate(b(n))
  b = a ! This copies the contents of the array a to the allocation for b

  return
end
```

Then in your main program there are a number of inexplicable things. Why are `i` and `j` declared as integers? Surely they must be pointers to real arrays, if the intention is to pass them to your `myalloc`, perform the allocation/copy operation on them, then print them? If that is the case, then changing your main to something like this should be closer to what it seems you are trying to do:

```
program main
    implicit none

    interface
        subroutine myalloc(a,b,n)
        real,dimension(n) :: a
        real,pointer,dimension(:) :: b 
        integer :: n
        end subroutine myalloc

        subroutine myprint(i)
        real,pointer,dimension(:) :: i
        end subroutine myprint
    end interface

    real,pointer,dimension(:) :: i, j
    real :: a(2)

    a=(/1.1,2.2/)
    call myalloc(a,i,2)

    a=(/3.1,4.2/)
    call myalloc(a,j,2)

    call myprint(i)
    call myprint(j)

    stop
end
```

With these changes, you should get this when run:

```
$ ./pointer
   1.100000       2.200000    
   3.100000       4.200000
```

Is that closer to what you were expecting as output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have explained my question more clearly. I need to have an structure that its details is hidden from the main program (only visible in subroutines that are going to be a closed source library). So I tried to use an integer for "i" and "j". I have seen similar thing in MPI library, e.g. MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(type,err), where type is declared as an integer and can possibly point to a structure. Here is another attempt that works, but I am not sure if "sType" components can be figured if "myMod" is compiled to a binary file. http://web.eng.ucsd.edu/~mesmaily/test.f

Comment: You probably want to use the `transfer` function to convert pointers from the externally visible type to an internal one used inside the library. Formally, Fortran 90 only supports strongly typed pointers, so you are probably in compiler/runtime specific beahviours trying to do this. If you can support F2003, the interoperability extensions might be worth investigating, with that you get the ability to handle proper void pointers, as in C. I must say that none of this was obvious from your original question....